# get error as string from error interface

Tags: go

How to get error as string from an error interface?

I want to assign `ERROR: Fake error!` to a variable and then convert it to a slice `[]byte(error_str)`

```
prefix_err := "ERROR: "

defer func() {
    if err := recover(); err != nil {
        // get error message from "err" as string
    }
}()

panic("Fake error!")
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need the error in a `[]byte`? My only guess is that you want to write it to a file, and `io.Writer` takes in a `[]byte`. If so, there are easier interfaces that take in strings.

Comment: What do you mean? And yes I'm writing to `os.Stderr` and a file

Comment: Use `fmt.Fprint[ln|f](io.Stderr, "my string")` In fact, you can substitute my answer with `fmt.Fprintf(io.Stderr, "%s%v\n", prefix_err, err)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different problems here:

The first problem: The actual `error` type is actually a built-in interface. To implement it you implement a method on the type `func Error() string`. So anything with the `error` type can be converted to a string format by calling its `Error` function.

The second problem: `panic` doesn't take in an `error`, it takes in an `interface{}`. The `recover` builtin similarly returns whatever `interface{}` you passed to `panic`. In this case, calling `Error` won't work. Indeed, you didn't pass an `error` into `panic`, you passed in a `string` (which is common).

There are a lot of ways you can get a `string` from an `interface{}`, and a big type switch is one. But overall I think the easiest option is

```
myBytes := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s%v", prefix_err, err))
```

Which will always get a string representation of whatever the interface{} was, calling `String()` or `Error()` as necessary, and then convert it into a `[]byte`.

(Minor footnote: it's not considered Go style to use underscores in variable names, use camelCase instead).

Edit:

Since it turns out we had a partial "X Y problem" with the conversion to a `[]byte` to write into an `io.Writer`. If you want to log this to Stderr, you can instead use `fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s%v\n", prefix_err, err)` or even `fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, prefix_err, err)`. Any `Fprint` will correctly print to any `io.Writer`, including a logfile.

Answer (score -1):

Panics do not always take the type of an Error. In your case you are passing in a string.

```
panic("Fake Error")

err := recover() // => string (interface)
```

To recover on an error interface, you need to pass an error

```
panic(fmt.Errorf("Fake Error!"))

err := recover() // => error (interface)
e := err.(error) // type check
e.Error()        // => string
```

If you are not quite sure which one you'll get, you can type check when you recover and handle accordingly.